# How can I make a static gameObject variable and show it in the inspector in order to assing the gameobject that I want?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, variables, static

I basically want to make a public static gameObject but it doesnt show it in the inspector.How can I assign the gameobject I want then?

Comment: Hi there. I recommend adding code you've tried so far so that people can see the context you are working in and suggest solutions accordingly.

Comment: [some solutions](https://answers.unity.com/questions/24289/is-it-possible-to-show-static-variables-in-the-ins.html). There are a few solutions for your problem that maybe you will want to see in the link.

Comment: Static `GameObject`s might be a bit _heavy_ considering there are precautions in Unity when using `static` at the best of times and the fact Unity wants to control object lifetimes.  Consider exposing a static POCO instead.  https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.3/Documentation/Manual/DomainReloading.html and https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ConfigurableEnterPlayModeDetails.html

Comment: People requesting closure should perhaps take note of _["Not all questions benefit from including code..."](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)_ and _[Is it always a good idea to demand the OP “post some code”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286760/585968)_

Answer (score 1):

Static cannot be shown in component instance because it is  "above" the component, it belongs to the class type and there is only one shared by all components of this type.

Your solution could be to find the game object and then assign it to the static variable.

```
public static GameObject TheStaticGO {get; private set;}

void Start()
{
    // Only assign if empty
    if(TheStaticGO == null){
        TheStaticGo = GameObject.Find("StaticGOName");
    }
}
```

Comment: theStaticGOName will be the objects name?

Comment: Yes, the GameObject you are looking for.

Comment: I was wondering, can I do it with tag instead of name? It would be so helpful.

Comment: Oh I change it to Tag but none of them works.Idk why the gameObject is supposed to go in the cords I want with  public Vector3 position = new Vector3(0, 5, -7);

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand you well. Suppose you have a static function and it should retrieve Object one time and not the other.
Then I would simply put Static under bool or 1x function with GameObject and 1x function without GameObject (you put these functions under the same name only without the corresponding GameObject)